# Removing spaces from text string in vba

Tags: vba, excel, delimiter, trim

I'm trying to debug a function in excel to do with delimiting tables using data from an imported text file. The macro has an issue when the name has a space in it (see example, second line) since the table is delimited using spaces. The code I currently have works fine for the first line of the example. A table exists with multiple lines similar to this.

Example of lines of table imported from text file

[image]

So the issue is when something like "WT 03" appears, has a space, the program crashes. I've tried trimming and find & replace but they don't work since the entire line is contained in the first column and separated by spaces. I only want to eliminated any spaces found within "Wt02" or "WT 03" when they occur.

Any suggestions or recommendations on where to look would be appreciated.

Comment: "The code I currently have works fine" - it would help if you posted that

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any control over the format of the data export?  If so, you should change it to use a different delimiter, like CSV ("WT 03","68.44","91.13"...).

If not, you could try separating the values by multiple spaces.  It looks like there are at least 5-6 spaces between legitimate fields, so try dividing them using the Split function as follows:

```
Dim MyArr() as String
MyArr = Split(InputTextLine, "     ")
```

And then trim each of the array values to remove excess spaces.